# How to color text of input element

Tags: jquery, css

I have a token input in my form, so I want every **comma-separated token** to have a different color background.  My question is how do I style every element by value, or can I use the id in the value?

I want

- red to use red background,
- blue to use blue background,
- green to use green background,
- etc

What do I do to accomplish this?  Here is my code:

```
<input value="red,blue,green"
       type="text"
       id="exampleInlineTags"
       class="form-control token-example-field"
       name="search"
       placeholder="Enter tags" />
```

Comment: You can use some jquery plugin e.g. jquery tagit. It will take care of separating tags, will give you more options like removing any tag by clicking close button and also you can style them any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot natively style the value of an input since it presumes the use of additional inner HTML tags (which is literal, you need real child elements!)

A workaround would be using a `contenteditable` DIV

```js
function toColorTokens() {
  $(this).html( // Remove whitespaces & Create our SPAN elements
    $(this).data("value").replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/[^,]+/g, function(m) {
      return "<span style='background:"+ m +";'>"+ m +"</span>";
    })
  ); 
}

function removeColorTokens() {
  $(this).text( $(this).data("value") );
}

function storeDataValue() {
  $(this).data("value", $.trim($(this).text()));
}

$("[contenteditable]").on({
  input    : storeDataValue,    // update data-value on input
  keypress : function(e) { return e.which !== 13; }, // Prevent Enter key
  focus    : removeColorTokens, // decolorify on focus
  blur     : toColorTokens      // colorify on blur
  
}).trigger("blur");             // Do it now!
```

```css
[contenteditable]{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:4px 8px;
  border-radius:3px;
}
[contenteditable]:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:attr(data-placeholder);
  color:#888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable data-value="red,green,blue,#F00BA4" data-placeholder="Enter tags"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! @dippas

Comment: great workaround, but i need to colorful Tokeninput, this is source
http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/
so every token got different background, do you know hot to ?